# document.getElementById().value is not Working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have been workin' on a project about employees
So there is some data in the mysql database. So to get that and put it into a html table I used php.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Stock_Management.`staff_details`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>
                <td scope='row'>".$row['id']."</td>
                <td>".$row['fname']."</td>
                <td>".$row['lname']."</td>
                <td>".$row['phno']."</td>
                <td>".$row['employee_address']."</td>
                <td>".$row['join_date']."</td>
                <td><i class='far fa-edit btnedit' value=".$row['id']." name='btn-edit' id='btn-edit' onclick='edit()' style='color: green; cursor: pointer'></i></td>
                <td><i class='far fa-trash-alt btndelete' value='".$row['id']."' name='btn-delete' id='btn-delete' onclick='delete()' style='color: tomato; cursor: pointer'></i></td>
            </tr>";
    }
}
```

So if you see the last two `td` tags you can see I used font awesome and gave them `values` respectively with `name` and `id` Attributes. And also `onclick` event with a function.

```
echo "<script>
    function edit(){
        let data_id = document.getElementById('btn-edit');
        console.log(data_id.value);
    }
</script>";
```

But Every time I am Getting `undefined` in the console. So what's Wrong with my code. Please Help Me!! Please.

Comment: Do you need to add quotes to the previous attribute `'".$row['id']."'`

Comment: `btn-edit` is an `<i>` element. Those don't have a `value` property.

Comment: @NigelRen No Bro, It ain't Working'..... BTW thanks for trying.

Comment: @Ivar So, what's the Alternative?

Comment: By your logic you are going to repeat the `id` which is a no-go. Change `function edit(){` to `function edit(element){` and pass it by using `onclick='edit(this)'`. Then you will not have to look for it. To get the `value` you would call `element.getAttribute('value')`.

Comment: You could be using `.getAttribute('value')` on the element. But [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) would probably be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @Lain Thanks, that Solves my Problem!!

Comment: Good to read. Think about @Ivar valid suggestion about using data attributes as well. Ultimately, you could just pass the id straight `edit(".$row['id'].")` if you do not need the actual HTML-Element.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value you could change js code to:

```
function edit(){
    console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

By clicking it browser creates event which you can target to get clicked value.

also, you are missing "'" around value  value=".$row['id']."
keep in mind that you should not have multiple occurrences of the same id on the page so targeting btn-edit will never work if you have multiple elements with this id.

You should not use "" tag for a button

Comment: This will not work due to `value` not being a property of `i`.

Comment: You should use something like < button > or < a > 
Lain - I couldn't edit my answer above so I replied here now.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'value' in your element to

```
data-value
```

Change the javascript line 'console.log(data_id.value);' to

```
console.log(data_id.dataset.value);
```

For more information on the use of js dataset visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Also, the `<i>` element does not contain the `value` property.

Answer (score 0):

1.you can not add value and name to tag `<i>`,you should use input tag,
2.if you use this, I hope you don't have any problem with that;

```
<label class='far fa-edit btnedit' onclick='edit()' style='color: green; cursor: pointer;font-size: 25px;'>
    <input type='hidden' id='btn-edit' name='btn_edit' value='".$row['id']."'/>
</label>


<script>
    function edit(){
        let data_id = document.getElementById('btn-edit');
        console.log(data_id.value);
    }
</script>
```